# Firestore moving to timestamps in Firebase functions

Tags: firebase, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Yesterday, all my firebase functions started throwing the following warning:

> The behavior for Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change
>   AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK. To hide this warning and ensure your app does
>   not break, you need to add the following code to your app before
>   calling any other Cloud Firestore methods:
>
> ```
> const firestore = new Firestore();
> const settings = {/* your settings... */ timestampsInSnapshots: true};  
> firestore.settings(settings);
> ```
>
> With this change, timestamps stored in Cloud Firestore will be read
>   back as Firebase Timestamp objects instead of as system Date objects.
>   So you will also need to update code expecting a Date to instead
>   expect a Timestamp. For example:
>
> ```
> // Old:   const date = snapshot.get('created_at');
> // New:   const timestamp = snapshot.get('created_at');   const date =
> timestamp.toDate();
> ```
>
> Please audit all existing usages of Date when you enable the new
>   behavior. In a future release, the behavior will change to the new
>   behavior, so if you do not follow these steps, YOUR APP MAY BREAK.

Now I want to init my firestore correctly according to this warning. i'm using typescript.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';    
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
let fireStoreDB = fireStoreDB || admin.firestore()
```

the firestore() that return from admin doesn't have a .settings() method as described in the warning nor it gets an object in the constructor. (It gets an App Object).
so I have two questions:

1. How can init my firestore to get the settings object?
2. when I insert a date to a document or when I query a document do I also need to pass the Firestore.Timestamp object? or can i query/insert the normal JS Date object and it will get converted automatically?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

i managed to solve it for http functions using :

```
if (!fireStoreDB){
    fireStoreDB = admin.firestore();
    fireStoreDB.settings(settings);
}
```

But it still is happening on firestore triggers.
anyone knows how to give default settings to admin on :

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

so it will not happen on firestore triggers?

Comment: I use JavaScript, not TypeScript and `admin.firestore().settings(...)` compiles for me.  What error do you get?

Comment: Property 'settings' does not exist on type 'Firestore'

Comment: AFAIK Firestore triggers use a separate Firestore client initialized internally by the Functions SDK. This instance uses its own settings, which currently does not include the timestampInSnapshots option.

Comment: Thank you Hiranya.... so nothing to do regarding this warning that happends repeatedly currently?

Comment: @ShaharWider, please have a look at my answer as after `firebase-admin` v7.0.0 there were some breaking changes introduced, regarding this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are still receiving JS Date instead of Firestore Timestamp due to a bug... now fixed in Firebase Functions v2.0.2.
See: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/releases/tag/v2.0.2.

For initialisation I've used `admin.firestore().settings({timestampsInSnapshots: true})` as specified in warning message, so the warning has disappeared.

When you add a date to a Document, or use as a query parameter, you can use the normal JS Date object.

Answer (score 4):

add below 2nd line code in your index.js firebase functions file

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);  
admin.firestore().settings( { timestampsInSnapshots: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it the following way:

```
const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true}; 
if (!fireStoreDB){
    fireStoreDB = admin.firestore();
    fireStoreDB.settings(settings);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For `firebase-admin` version 7.0.0 or above**

You should not be getting this error anymore.

In [Version 7.0.0 - January 31, 2019](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node) of `firebase-admin` there were some [breaking changes](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/releases/tag/v0.20.0) introduced:

> **BREAKING: The `timestampsInSnapshots` default has changed to true.**
>
> The `timestampsInSnapshots` setting is now enabled by default so timestamp
>   fields read from a `DocumentSnapshot` will be returned as `Timestamp` objects
>   instead of `Date`. Any code expecting to receive a `Date` object must be
>   updated.

**Note:** As stated in [the official docs](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.20.x/Firestore#Firestore), `timestampsInSnapshots` is going to be removed in a future release so make sure to remove it altogether.

**For older versions of `firebase-admin` (6.5.1 and below)**

This should do the work:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const firestore = admin.firestore();

// Add this magical line of code:
firestore.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });
```

Then in your function use the firestore object directly:

```
firestore.doc(`/mycollection/${id}`).set({ it: 'works' })
```